# Can the session opened by OSIV initialize a proxy if the parent entity that contains the proxy is not present in the session?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

If we fetch an entity using `entityManager.find()` and that entity has a collection that is fetched lazily, we know that the collection won't be initialized right away. Rather instead of the real collection, a wrapper collection will be there which consists of proxies.

Now, if `OSIV` is enabled, the session will remain open for the entire scope of a request and if we try to iterate through the collection or invoke any other method on the collection, the collection will be initialized as the session opened by `OSIV` Interceptor/Filter is still open.

My question is if we keep the collection uninitialized and try to initialize it by using the session opened by a new request, will we still get a `LazyInitializationException`?

Answer (score 0):

But in order to make the session (aka `EntityManager`) in the new request can initialise the collection, you have to make the `EntityManager` to manage the entity first.

Because from the `EntityManager` that does not load this entity 's point of view ,it is a detached entity and not managed. You can make it be managed by that `EntityManager` by calling `.merge()` on it.

And as long the `EntityManager` that manages this entity is not closed , you would not get `LazyInitializationException`.